# Getting data from SQL through Store Procedures using Azure Function

Tags: c#, sql, azure-functions

I want to run a stored procedure through Azure function which return rows from SQL Table. I am getting response 200 OK.  but I am not able to print those rows in output window. Below is my code -

```
#r "System.Data"
using System.Net;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");


dynamic body = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var e = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(body as string);



//Connect to SQL
var cnnString  = "XXXX";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
{


    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GET_TOP_5_APP", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@USERID", e.param1));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SM", e.param2));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SY", e.param3));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EM", e.param4));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EY", e.param5));

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}

return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Ok");
}

public class Person
{
    public string param1 {get;set;}
    public string param2 {get;set;}
    public string param3 {get;set;}
    public string param4 {get;set;}
    public string param5 {get;set;}
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obviously, you need to iterate through rows with your `reader`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Mikhail, Thanks for your reply, for all my attempts it started throwing " Status: 500 Internal Server Error" , can you please give any example

Comment: Basically, you are asking to write code for you, which is not exactly the purpose of stack overflow. It's basic ADO.NET usage, you can find it anywhere online. Nothing specific to Functions, so you can write and debug this code as console application first, and then copy to Function.

Comment: Take a look at the [second code sample here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader) for an example of looping through the result of the reader.

Comment: Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the values using below code.

```
 SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        var kk=reader.GetValue(0) + " - " + reader.GetValue(1) + " - " + reader.GetValue(2);
        log.Info(kk.ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding more to @pramoad answer to have flexibility for retrieving specific row data with column name

```
while (reader.Read())
   {
      var kk = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Column1")) + " - " + reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Column2")) + " - " + reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Column3")) + " - " + reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Column4"));
      log.Info(kk.ToString());
  }
```